# array elements added or missing in javascript function

Tags: javascript, arrays, function

This code appends an extra element to the first generated menus every time the function is called. The last element in each array is missing in all subsequent calls. I can't seem to figure out why this is happening.

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">

var elements = ['one','two','three','etc'];

var positions = ['Producer', 'Tech', 'Assist', 'Voice'];

function addNamelist() {

  var q = document.createElement('select');
    for (var j=0; j<positions.length; j++) {
        q.setAttribute('id', positions[j]);
        document.body.appendChild(q);
        var r = document.createElement('option');
        r.setAttribute('value', positions[j]);    
        var m = document.createTextNode(positions[j]);
        r.appendChild(m);
        document.getElementById(positions[j]).appendChild(r);
    } 
  var y = document.createElement('select');
    for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
      y.setAttribute('id', elements[i]);
      document.body.appendChild(y);
      var z = document.createElement('option');
      z.setAttribute('value', elements[i]);
      var t = document.createTextNode(elements[i]);
      z.appendChild(t);
      document.getElementById(elements[i]).appendChild(z);    
    }   
}
</script>
</head>

<body>
<form action="editpageentry.php"><form>
<a href="#" onclick="addNamelist()">create field</a>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You know you're setting the ID and appending the select inside the loop, so you're doing it once for every option ?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/gp5svh83/

Comment: It seems to do what I want at jsfiddle.net.  Not doing it in Chrome, though. Thanks.